# Windows machine sounds not playing (Beep() etc)

Tags: windows-7, audio

So this has been an issue for a while now, and it's starting to annoy me.
Some sounds just does not work, and I have no idea why.

- Sound overall works. I can listen to music etu (youtube, spotify
  blabla)
- Sound when switching folders work, and the sound when UAC pops up.

However, sounds like [Beep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) and error sounds does not work. I've tried fiddling around in sound settings, but I can't make it work. It just stopped making a noise one day, and I spent an hour debugging my software as to why the Beep wasn't being called, and turns out, I just couldn't hear it.

Anyone experienced this weird bug before?

Edit: I obviously want to solve this problem.

Edit 2: I've tried different audio outputs, and it's not solving the problem. I've tried going through the Windows Sounds and try to manually assign the beep sound, but I can't find anything.

Comment: I have a monitor (Asus VH222H) and a TV as a monitor connected to my computer. The Asus monitor has an annoying feature whereby it fades sound in, which *usually* misses isolated beeps and other short sounds. The TV plays the sounds faultlessly. Could your monitor be doing the same?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. So, is your question simply to know if anyone else has experienced this same thing? Or are you trying to figure out how to resolve it? Please clarify your question by using the [edit] link.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Most likely not. I tried running Beep for 5 seconds, and it did not produce any sound still.

Comment: @CharlieRB See edit. :)

Comment: Now that we've established you want it resolved :-), I have a few more questions. Do the sound files exist in `C:\Windows\Media`? Can they be played directly from that location with a media player?

Comment: Are system sounds muted in the Volume Mixer?

Comment: @CharlieRB It does not exist in the folder, however I wouldn't expect it to be there either. Or am I wrong? And no, the system sound is not muted, and when I click on "test sound" for the system sounds, it plays a sound.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question. Are you asking about **Windows** System Sounds played inside Windows triggered by various events?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, and specifically [this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) does not play. See video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rNPsOhBXPQ

Comment: @pnda Those sounds should be in C:\Windows\Media. Do you know of any reason they would not be there?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, if this somehow is not working, it can be a real pain to find it.

Go to `Control Panel` -> `System` - > `Device Manager`

From the menu `View` enable `Show hidden devices`.

Open the `Non-Plug and Play Drivers` section, and look for `Beep`

Double click it, head to the `Drivers` tab, and make sure its started. Also make sure the Startup type is set to `System`.

Also under `System devices` locate `System speaker` and make sure its enabled.

This will ensure that any error beep will play. If you want to customise the sound, you can do so from `Control Panel` -> `Sound`.

Comment: Hello! I tried that just before you submitted your answer, and it still isn't working. Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rNPsOhBXPQ (360p until youtube finishes processing)